# Make a function that groups new variables

Tags: r, function, data.table

I have this kind of dataset;

```
dt <- data.table(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                 q1= c(1, NA, NA, 1), 
                 q2= c(1, 3, 2, NA), 
                 q3= c(2, 1, 4, 4))
```

I need to make new variables based on q1, q2, q3, but i want to group the values;
so its should be that all with value 1, 2 = YES, all with value 3 = NO, all with value 4 = IDK

So final dataset should be

```
ID q1 q2 q3 q1_cat q2_cat q3_cat
1  1  1  2   YES     YES     YES     
2  NA 3  1   NA      NO      YES 
3  NA 2  4  NA       NO      IDK
4  1 NA  4  YES      NA      IDK
```

Comment: I don't know ‘data.table’ so I can’t provide a specific answer but the *general* solution to this kind of problem is to first transform your data into long form (i.e. one observation per `q`), map the values, and then transform the data back into wide format. Of course often you can “cheat” and forgo the reshaping (as both solutions posted so far illustrate) but it’s a good general pattern to be aware of, because it makes a large class of problems trivial to solve.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  q1 = c(1, NA, NA, 1),
  q2 = c(1, 3, 2, NA),
  q3 = c(2, 1, 4, 4)
)

df |> 
  mutate(across(
    starts_with("q"),
    \(x) case_match(x, c(1, 2) ~ "yes", 3 ~ "no"),
    .names = "{.col}_cat"
  ))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 7
#>      ID    q1    q2    q3 q1_cat q2_cat q3_cat
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1     1     1     1     2 yes    yes    yes   
#> 2     2    NA     3     1 <NA>   no     yes   
#> 3     3    NA     2     4 <NA>   yes    <NA>  
#> 4     4     1    NA     4 yes    <NA>   <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In base R

```r
setDF(dt)
dt[,5:7] <- setNames(lapply(dt[,-1], function(x) c('YES', 'YES', 'NO', 'IDK')[x]),
                     paste0(names(dt[-1]), '_cat'))
```

result:

```r
dt
#>   ID q1 q2 q3 q1_cat q2_cat q3_cat
#> 1  1  1  1  2    YES    YES    YES
#> 2  2 NA  3  1   <NA>     NO    YES
#> 3  3 NA  2  4   <NA>    YES    IDK
#> 4  4  1 NA  4    YES   <NA>    IDK
```

Comment: what if i have mulitple q variables? fx 34?

Comment: It's exactly the same code, except you would need to write the columns to the correct indices (e.g. if your first column is ID and you have 34 variables then you need to write them to `dt[,36:79]`

Comment: what if i have other variables than ID besides the q1, fx ge, sex etc. how can I do this?

Comment: It's really difficult to answer supplementary questions in the comments without concrete examples @Hellihansen. If it's difficult to extend my code to your actual data set, it might be better to post a new question with an example that you would be confident that you could apply to your own data.